# Static factory methods instead of constructors

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, flyweight-pattern

I've been researching this after I read Joshua Block's Effective Java Book, Item 1, about using factory static methods instead of constructors. There in the text he defends the use, whenever possible and cites, among other justifications, the possibility of implementing the *Singleton* or *Flyweight* standards. It also cites the case of the `Boolean` class, which wisely uses *Flyweight* through the `valueOf (boolean)` method:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

My question is: I understand the advantages of using these patterns, but could not be implemented in the constructor itself? Their use alone does not justify the creation of a static factory method.

Comment: You can check this https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/02/5-difference-between-constructor-and-factory-method-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but could not be implemented in the constructor itself?

No: `new`, by specification, *always* creates a new instance (or fails), so `new Boolean(b)` would always return a new instance of `Boolean`.

`Boolean.valueOf` returns a pre-existing instance. This is desirable, because there are only two possible values, so there is simply no point in creating more.

Comment: And how to deal with a dependency injection issue when you become a private builder? Is it possible to use DI when using this building strategy?

Comment: @dellasavia I'm not sure what you are asking. Consider that constructors are effectively just special static methods: the DI implications of using static factory methods are the same as using constructors

Comment: I did mean when using a framework to inject like Spring. How it knows which is the constructor method that will be used?

Comment: @dellasavia I can't answer for Spring, but with Guice you have to have an explicit `@Provides` method.