# Joshua Bloch Item #1 Static Factory Methods Instead of Constructors - Object creation

Tags: java, static-methods, factory-method, effective-java

## Source of Question

I was wondering about the following advantage of Static Factory Methods described by Joshua Blochs "Effective Java", 3rd edition  in item #1:

> A second advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they are not required to create a new object each time they’re invoked. This allows immutable classes (Item 15) to use preconstructed instances, or to cache instances as they’re constructed, and dispense them repeatedly to avoid creating unnecessary duplicate objects. The Boolean.valueOf(boolean) method illustrates this technique: it never creates an object.

See extract [here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151).

## Question

What got my attention was the last line about `valueOf(boolean)` not creating an object.
According to the book

```java
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

and the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(boolean))

> `public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b)`
>
> Returns a Boolean instance representing the specified boolean value. If the specified boolean value is true, this method returns Boolean.TRUE; if it is false, this method returns Boolean.FALSE. If a new Boolean instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Boolean(boolean), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.

So from my understanding and the Javadoc ("Returns a Boolean instance...") the static method returns indeed a Boolean and therefore an object - as it is literally the return type. In the following case:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Boolean booleanWrapped = Boolean.valueOf(true);
        System.out.println(booleanWrapped);
    }
}
```

`booleanWrapped` is my object I can use e.g. like in the `prinln()` statement.

So what am I missing here if Joshua states

> The Boolean.valueOf(boolean) [...] **never** creates an object

I'm aware of a similar question with an existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58544419/20926873) but it doesn't seem to fully answer my question as in my example above there isn't an "pre-existing" instance.?!

Comment: The method doesn't create any objects, it just returns the values of `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE` that were created once when the `Boolean` class was loaded.

Comment: There is a difference between **returning** an object which already exists (`Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`) vs. **creating** a new object.

Comment: booleanWrapped does not reference a newly *created* object. It references the static Boolean.TRUE created the first time the Boolean class loads.

Comment: A `Boolean` is an _immutable_ object (its internal state cannot be changed). There are only two possible boolean values.  When class `Boolean` is loaded and initialized it creates two static instances, TRUE and FALSE.  Therefore, there is never any reason to instantiate a `Boolean` object, every `Boolean` reference can point to one of the two static values created at `Boolean` class initialization time.  `valueOf()` returns one of those two references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Java 9, Boolean has a deprecated constructor.  But this still demonstrates the difference.

So `Boolean b1 = new Boolean(true).` creates a new instance and stores it in `b1`.

```
Boolean b1 = new Boolean(true);
Boolean b2 = new Boolean(true);
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b1));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b2));
```

Two different identity hashcodes imply different objects

```
804564176
1421795058
```

Now use the existing static instance.

```
Boolean b1 = Boolean.TRUE;
Boolean b2 = Boolean.TRUE;
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b1));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b2));
```

Sharing the same object - same hashcode.

```
804564176
804564176
```

Within the Boolean class you have the following:

```
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);
```

So they are created when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Your booleanWrapped variable does not reference a newly **created** object. It references the static `Boolean.TRUE` created the first time the Boolean class loads. All calls to `Boolean.valueOf(true)` simply reuse that single object.

Answer (score 1):

The method `valueOf` never creates a new object (there is no `new` expression and no other method call that could transitively call a constructor). The method simply returns one of 2 static fields (`Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`). These fields already exist and the objects they reference were already created (outside and before the method `valueOf`).

Obviously, the objects have to be created *somewhere*; but they are not created in the method `valueOf`.

And "returning an object" != "creating an object".

```
public static Object demo() {
  final Object obj = new Object(); // `new` creates the object
  return obj; // `return` returns the object, it does not create a new one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` are pre-existing `static` members defined by the Boolean class.

One important concept to not overlook in understanding the benefit of static factory methods over traditional constructors is why Josh Bloch specifies that *immutable* classes can be cached or pre-constructed. The point isn't really about whether or not a single object is constructed at the time that static factory method is called the first time, but rather how it can conserve resources when used multiple times.  The savings is all about returning a pre-existing immutable instance rather than constructing a new one.